# Особенности передачи float в функцию Си, которая находится в другом модуле

Tags: c

Есть две функции на C: main() и f1():

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    float count = 11.07;
    double num = 7.25;
    int n = 11;

    printf("\n(main:) %3.2f : %3.2f : %3d\n", count, num, n);
    f1(count, num, n);
    return 0;
}

#include <stdio.h>

void f1(float count, double res, int n) {

    printf("(f1):   %3.2f : %3.2f : %3d\n\n", count, res, n);

}
```

Вот результат работы функции main():

(main:) 11.07 : 7.25 :  11
(f1):   0.00 : 7.25 :  11

Почему некорректно передается первый параметр float?
Особенности компилятора gcc?

Выходной файл был собран так:
$ gcc -c main.c f1.
$ gcc main.o f1.o -o ./111
$ ./111 (результат выше)

Мне кажется, происходит неявное преобразование float в double.
Дело в том, что не могу изменить сигнатуру файла f1() - он внешний.
Помогите, плз, советом.

Заранее спасибо!!

Comment: У вас есть где-то объявление функции `f1`? Откуда компилятор в `main.c` знает ее сигнатуру?

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку у вас в первом файле нет объявления функции `f1`, компилятор не знает, как именно ее вызывать и передавать в нее аргументы. В результате функция вызывается *не так, как должна*.

Эксперимент с компилятором VC++ показал то же, что происходит у вас. Но стоило перед `int main...` добавить строчку

```
void f1(float count, double res, int n);
```

как все стало совершенно верно работать.

Кстати, компилятор выдал предупреждение о необъявленной функции:

> warning C4013: f1: нет определения; предполагается "extern" с возвратом типа "int"

Comment: Все так и есть, порядок! У меня был просто вопрос, почему другие параметры передались правильно, а параметр с типом float - нет.
Я думал, что эти вопросы решает компилятор gcc и линкер.
Но это я так думал, а Ваше решение - верное.

Comment: типы `float` и `double` имеют разный формат хранения, но в одном регистре. вызов в `main` неправильно передаёт тип `float`, потому-что он не знал, каким способом функция `f1` всё воспримет и передал, предполагая, что функция примет как тип `double`. @GreyKoshak

Comment: Спасибо! Вопрос понятен.